# exception on the class EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class when using spring boot 1.4.1 and spring data(elasticseach)

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat7

when using the above dependencies and deploying on tomcat 7 or 8 using jdk 7 
i got the run time exception bellow :

```
2016-10-19 16:27:17.103 ERROR 9356 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer.addErrorPages([Lorg/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ErrorPage;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5520) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer.addErrorPages([Lorg/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ErrorPage;)V
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$ErrorPageCustomizer.customize(ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java:269) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:68) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1575) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted

2016-10-19 16:27:17.103 ERROR 9356 --- [ina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start
```

I have tried to deploy on tomcat 7 and tomcat 8, but no luck 
and i have tried to compile the code using jdk 7 and jdk 8 
still no luck there

Comment: what are you trying to do? Are you trying to deploy to separate tomcat instance a spring boot application already having an embedded tomcat instance?

Comment: I am trying to deploy on a separate tomcat, I have tried to deploy first on tomcat 7 and then on tomcat 8.  I hope I have answered your question correctly

Comment: so have you followed manual instructions on how to do non-embbeded, deployable spring boot app? say [this](http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/)?

Comment: yes I  already have a war deployed on tomcat, but I wanted to add an integration with elastic search

Comment: based on your stack trace, it doesn't seem your war configuration was done correctly. You shouldn't be having EmbbeddedTomcatContainer in use if it were.

Comment: You are mixing Spring Boot 1.4.1 and 1.3.7 classes...Never mix versions of a framework.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by excluding the above class(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class) from the starter spring boot class:

```
@ComponentScan("net.*")
@SpringBootApplication   
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={ElasticsearchJestDataAutoConfiguration.class,DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class, ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class,EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class})
//@EnableConfigurationProperties(ElasticsearchProperties.class)
//@EnableElasticsearchRepositories
@ImportResource({"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
public class PaymentBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(PaymentBootApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(PaymentBootApplication.class);

    }
```